# Rarely executed and almost empty if statement drastically reduces performance in C++

Tags: c++, performance, if-statement

**Editor's clarification:** When this was originally posted, there were two issues:

- Test performance drops by a factor of three if seemingly inconsequential statement added
- Time taken to complete the test appears to vary randomly

The second issue has been solved: the randomness only occurs when running under the debugger.

The remainder of this question should be understood as being about the first bullet point above, and in the context of running in VC++ 2010 Express's Release Mode with optimizations "Maximize Speed" and "favor fast code".

There are still some Comments in the comment section talking about the second point but they can now be disregarded.

---

I have a simulation where if I add a simple if statement into the while loop that runs the actual simulation, the performance drops about a factor of three (and I run a lot of calculations in the while loop, n-body gravity for the solar system besides other things) even though the if statement is almost never executed:

```
if (time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000)
{
    cb_last_orbital_update = time;
}
```

with `time` and `cb_last_orbital_update` being both of type `double` and defined in the beginning of the main function, where this if statement is too. Usually there are computations I want to run there too, but it makes no difference if I delete them. The if statement as it is above has the same effect on the performance.

The variable `time` is the simulation time, it increases in 0.001 steps in the beginning so it takes a really long time until the if statement is executed for the first time (I also included printing a message to see if it is being executed, but it is not, or at least only when it's supposed to). Regardless, the performance drops by a factor of 3 even in the first minutes of the simulation when it hasn't been executed once yet. If I comment out the line

```
cb_last_orbital_update = time;
```

then it runs faster again, so it's not the check for

```
time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000
```

either, it's definitely the simple act of writing current simulation time into this variable.

Also, if I write the current time into another variable instead of `cb_last_orbital_update`, the performance does not drop. So this might be an issue with assigning a new value to a variable that is used to check if the "if" should be executed? These are all shots in the dark though.

Disclaimer: I am pretty new to programming, and sorry for all that text.

I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express, deactivating the `stdafx.h` precompiled header function didn't make a difference either.

EDIT: Basic structure of the program. Note that nowhere besides at the end of the while loop (`time += time_interval;`) is `time` changed. Also, `cb_last_orbital_update` has only 3 occurrences: Declaration / initialization, plus the two times in the if statement that is causing the problem.

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    double time = 0;
    double time_interval = 0.001;
    double cb_last_orbital_update = 0;

    F_Rocket_Preset(time, time_interval, ...);

    while(conditions)
    {
    Rocket[active].Stage[Rocket[active].r_stage].F_Update_Stage_Performance(time, time_interval, ...);
    Rocket[active].F_Calculate_Aerodynamic_Variables(time);
    Rocket[active].F_Calculate_Gravitational_Forces(cb_mu, cb_pos_d, time);
    Rocket[active].F_Update_Rotation(time, time_interval, ...);
    Rocket[active].F_Update_Position_Velocity(time_interval, time, ...);
    Rocket[active].F_Calculate_Orbital_Elements(cb_mu);
    F_Update_Celestial_Bodies(time, time_interval, ...);

    if (time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000.0)
    {
        cb_last_orbital_update = time;
    }

    Rocket[active].F_Check_Apoapsis(time, time_interval);
    Rocket[active].F_Status_Check(time, ...);
    Rocket[active].F_Update_Mass (time_interval, time);
    Rocket[active].F_Staging_Check (time, time_interval);

    time += time_interval;

    if (time > 3.1536E8)
    {
        std::cout << "\n\nBreak main loop! Sim Time: " << time << std::endl;
        break;
    }
    }
...
}
```

EDIT 2:

[Here](https://www.diffchecker.com/s8phnhz8) is the difference in the assembly code. On the left is the fast code with the line

```
cb_last_orbital_update = time;
```

outcommented, on the right the slow code with the line.

EDIT 4:

So, i found a workaround that seems to work just fine so far:

```
int cb_orbit_update_counter = 1; // before while loop

if(time - cb_orbit_update_counter * 5E6 > 0)
{
    cb_orbit_update_counter++;
}
```

EDIT 5:

While that workaround does work, it only works in combination with using `__declspec(noinline)`. I just removed those from the function declarations again to see if that changes anything, and it does.

EDIT 6: Sorry this is getting confusing. I tracked down the culprit for the lower performance when removing `__declspec(noinline)` to this function, that is being executed inside the `if`:

```
__declspec(noinline) std::string F_Get_Body_Name(int r_body)
{
switch (r_body)
{
case 0:
    {
        return ("the Sun");
    }
case 1:
    {
        return ("Mercury");
    }
case 2:
    {
        return ("Venus");
    }
case 3:
    {
        return ("Earth");
    }
case 4:
    {
        return ("Mars");
    }
case 5:
    {
        return ("Jupiter");
    }
case 6:
    {
        return ("Saturn");
    }
case 7:
    {
        return ("Uranus");
    }
case 8:
    {
        return ("Neptune");
    }
case 9:
    {
        return ("Pluto");
    }
case 10:
    {
        return ("Ceres");
    }
case 11:
    {
        return ("the Moon");
    }
default:
    {
        return ("unnamed body");
    }
}

}
```

The `if` also now does more than just increase the counter:

```
if(time - cb_orbit_update_counter * 1E7 > 0)
{
    F_Update_Orbital_Elements_Of_Celestial_Bodies(args);
    std::cout << F_Get_Body_Name(3) << " SMA: " << cb_sma[3] << "\tPos Earth: " << cb_pos_d[3][0] << " / " << cb_pos_d[3][1] << " / " << cb_pos_d[3][2] <<
    "\tAlt: " << sqrt(pow(cb_pos_d[3][0] - cb_pos_d[0][0],2) + pow(cb_pos_d[3][1] - cb_pos_d[0][1],2) + pow(cb_pos_d[3][2] - cb_pos_d[0][2],2)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Time: " << time << "\tcb_o_h[3]: " << cb_o_h[3] << std::endl;
    cb_orbit_update_counter++;
}
```

I remove `__declspec(noinline)` from the function `F_Get_Body_Name` alone, the code gets slower. Similarly, if i remove the execution of this function or add `__declspec(noinline)` again, the code runs faster. All other functions still have `__declspec(noinline)`.

EDIT 7:
So i changed the switch function to

```
const std::string cb_names[] = {"the Sun","Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune","Pluto","Ceres","the Moon","unnamed body"}; // global definition
const int cb_number = 12; // global definition

std::string F_Get_Body_Name(int r_body)
{
if (r_body >= 0 && r_body < cb_number)
{
    return (cb_names[r_body]);
}
else
{
    return (cb_names[cb_number]);
}
}
```

and also made another part of the code slimmer. The program now runs fast without any `__declspec(noinline)`. As ElderBug suggested, an issue with the CPU instruction cache then / the code getting too big?

Answer (score 20):

I'd put my money on Intel's branch predictor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predictor

The processor assumes (time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000) to be false most of the time and loads up the execution pipeline accordingly.

Once the condition (time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000) comes true. The misprediction delay is hitting you. You may loose 10 to 20 cycles.

```
if (time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000)
{
    cb_last_orbital_update = time;
}
```

Comment: Hm, but doesn't that mean it should only be slower for those rare occasions it is true? The performance drop is all the time, even when it hasn't even executed once.

Comment: True, but this happens only once every 5,000,000 / 0.001 executions. So probably not that big of a deal.

Comment: @Kenira how do you measure the speed ? I'm asking because your loop will run for several billion iteration before your `time - cb_last_orbital_update > 5000000` condition is true. How long does one loop take ?

Comment: It could also be a rare'ish branch prediction aliasing symptom.   One of his subroutines could map to the same entry in the branch prediction logic and thus the branch prediction could be thrashing back and forth based on two different branches at two different instruction memory locations.  Fiddling with the code would offset the location of the branch and cause a different branch prediction entry to be used, thus not causing branch prediction thrash.

Comment: I noticed it without measuring the time since i have output that comes in certain simulation time periods, quite easy to judge. Measuring the time just now gave me 48.3s vs 17s so about a factor of three.

Comment: @Kenira ok, fair enough I guess. Might I ask : why do you have this condition ? you only update `cb_last_orbital_update` and you never use it anywhere else  apparently.

Comment: try this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b3fsfxw%28VS.80%29.aspx

In gcc I'd use likely/unlikely, a quick search revealed that the corresponding in msvc is __assume. It will hint the compiler that a certain condition is unlikely to be true/false.  I'm curious about the results! On gcc in some cases it makes quite a big dfference

Comment: @Félix: Usually i run a bunch of computations in the "if" too, i deleted everything else to narrow down the problem which turned out to be the line "cb_last_orbital_update = time;". Even with other computations still there, deleting this line will speed everything up again.

Comment: @Kenira, wait, so... replacing your if-statement's contents `cb_last_orbital_update = time;` with some other computations (i.e., not only removing the contents, but also adding some other calculations) speeds up the program again?

Comment: Yes. I can even just replace cb_last_orbital_update with another variable and write the time into that, no problem. I can put in there heavy calculations of any kind, no problem. It is only a problem with cb_last_orbital_update, which is why i guess it has to do with it also being in the "if" condition.

Comment: @dau_sama: trying to use __assume, but either i am using it wrong or it does not help.

Comment: @Kenira just to be sure, you're compiling with the highest optimization level enabled?

Comment: In Properties, C/C++, Optimization i have set "Optimization" to "Maximize Speed", and favor fast code. Not sure if other options are relevant too? EDIT: And just for clarification, i have put "__assume (time - cb_last_orbital_update < 1);" in front of the if.

Comment: @dau_sama: Okay so i played around a bit more, and it is now working with __assume(cb_last_orbital_update == 0);. I probably just used it wrong before. I still don't really understand how this is a problem, but i am happy to have at least a workaround now, so thank you :)

Comment: @Kenira glad to hear, oversimplifying basically the cpu branch predictor has to figure out every time which branch to take. With that instruction, you generate specific CPU code to tell it which branch is more likely to occur, and you hit less instruction cache misses. Now, usually branch predictors are quite smart and remember which branches have been taken in the past, but if meanwhile you go through too many other branches, the CPU has to drop the cache and hit a miss next time.

Comment: It's not so much "code to tell the CPU which way the branch will go", but rather "lay out the branch so the default (no prediction history available) predicted path is the common case".  IIRC, the default is to predict not-taken, since the following instructions are already fetched.  And yes, a big loop with a lot of stuff going on could fill up the branch history buffer.

Comment: Confusingly, I think that 'not taking the branch' generally means 'assuming the condition is true', because `if` statements are generally implemented as conditionally jumping over the contents of the if statement.

Answer (score 6):

Something is happening that you don't expect.

One candidate is some uninitialised variables hanging around somewhere, which have different values depending on the exact code that you are running. For example, you might have uninitialised memory that is sometime a denormalised floating point number, and sometime it's not.

I think it should be clear that your code doesn't do what you expect it to do. So try debugging your code, compile with all warnings enabled, make sure you use the same compiler options (optimised vs. non-optimised can easily be a factor 10). Check that you get the same results.

Especially when you say "it runs faster again (this doesn't always work though, but i can't see a pattern). Also worked with changing 5000000 to 5E6 once. It only runs fast once though, recompiling causes the performance to drop again without changing anything. One time it ran slower only after recompiling twice." it looks quite likely that you are using different compiler options.

Comment: As i just now noticed, the randomness is an issue with the compiler. If i run the exe directly, there is no randomness. The problem still exists though, if i delete the one line in the if or substitute it with other (heavy) calculations, it runs significantly faster.

Comment: @Kenira I think you mean *the IDE*, not *the compiler*.  The compiler is a program which turns your code into an executable. The compiler doesn't run the executable.

Answer (score 4):

I will try another guess. This is hypothetical, and would be mostly due to the compiler.

My guess is that you use a lot of floating point calculations, and the introduction and use of double values in your main makes the compiler run out of XMM registers (the floating point SSE registers). This force the compiler to use memory instead of registers, and induce a lot of swapping between memory and registers, thus greatly reducing the performance. This would be happening mainly because of the computations functions inlining, because function calls are preserving registers.

The solution would be to add `__declspec(noinline)` to ALL your computation functions declarations.

Comment: Sadly, that did not solve the problem, i added it to every function declaration.

Comment: @Kenira I'm out of ideas. Maybe you can check the generated assembly, and post the differences you can see between the fast and slow code ?

Comment: You possibly could eliminate this possibility as the cause by having a simple integer test (incrementing counter that triggers when you get `(5000000.0 / step-size)` times through the main loop).

Comment: Okay, so one: the randomness is just from the compiler. If i directly run the exe, it's always the same. Still, the program runs much faster when i outcomment the line, so the problem still exists. Also, i added a link to the assembler differences in the question at the bottom.

Comment: While using the new workaround with the `int`, I just removed `__declspec(noinline)` again to see if there is a difference and there is! The same difference in performance of about 3 to 1. It seems you were right all along, although it did also depend on how this if statement was set up. A question i now have is now that it seems that the registers are the problem, will this become a problem again in the future if i extend my code, using more and more doubles (i do need a lot)? Or will the use of `__declspec(noinline)` free up so much of the XMM registers again that that is unlikely?

Comment: @Kenira What bugs me is that you found a performance difference between the two assemblies you posted. Both are not inlining calls, so the register use is the same. I highly doubt the problem is branch prediction, since the branch is really predictable, and one misprediction should be negligible anyway. Maybe you mis-measured the performance because of the IDE ? That would explain much. Also, the registers in your case are the x87 stack registers, and not XMM (but that probably doesn't change anything).

Comment: @Kenira About register use, if the performance drop is really due to lack of register, then using function calls should be enough since all the x87 registers are freed on call. Wrapping heavy computation algorithm in separate function (and force noinline) may improve performance. Also, if it really is the cause, the compiler is at fault. It should detect this kind of things. Maybe upgrading to VS2013 can improve something.

Comment: @ElderBug: Okay. But i have more news again, i narrowed down the function that causes the performance drop when removing `__declspec(noinline)` to a switch function with currently 12 cases (which is executed inside the `if` that i was talking about all along) that does not use floating points at all, it simply prints a string on the screen. Sounds like a branching issue again?  I added the code of the function in the question. Sorry, this is all getting confusing.

Comment: @ElderBug: As for the performance, it doesn't matter if i execute the program via IDE in "Run without debugging" mode, or if i manually start the exe via the explorer. Performance difference is exactly the same with those two methods.

Comment: @Kenira About the switch function, it looks like it is fast in itself, but the generated code is huge. When inlined, it is probably polluting the CPU instruction cache and slowing the rest of the code. You can speed up the function and minimize its size using a simple array `std::string bodies[] = {"sun","moon",...}` and retrieving the name with `return bodies[r_body]`. Instruction cache may also be the cause of the first problem, as forcing noinline may induce a better cache utilization.

Comment: @ElderBug: Doing that and shortening another part of the code helped. The program now runs fast without any `__declspec(noinline)`. It is even a bit faster now too (10s instead of 10.2s). Seems i just gotta watch out more for optimizing the code, not only for speed but size too. Thanks you so much, you were a really big help :) If you create another answer saying what you did here in the comments, i could mark that as the best one.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using the Microsoft [Profile Guided Optimizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/e7k32f4k.aspx) -- if the compiler is making the wrong assumption for this particular branch it will help, and it will in all likelihood improve speed for the rest of the code as well.

Comment: I tried to use that, but i'm not getting far. As usual, microsoft tutorials are really not noob friendly. I managed to find the /GL and  /LTCG:PGINSTRUMENT options, but no .pgd file is created and i have no idea what i'm doing wrong because i'm mostly just guessing what to do anyway. You don't happen to know a good, step by step tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

Workaround, try 2:

The code is now looking like this:

```
int cb_orbit_update_counter = 1; // before while loop

if(time - cb_orbit_update_counter * 5E6 > 0)
{
    cb_orbit_update_counter++;
}
```

So far it runs fast, plus the code is being executed when it should as far as i can tell. Again only a workaround, but if this proves to work all around then i'm satisfied.

After some more testing, seems good.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that this is because the variable `cb_last_orbital_update` is otherwise read-only, so when you assign to it inside the `if`, it destroys some optimizations that the compiler has for read-only variables (e.g. perhaps it's now stored in memory instead of a register).

Something to try (although this *might still not work*) is to make a third variable that is initialized via `cb_last_orbital_update` and `time` depending on whether the condition is true, and using that one instead. Presumably, the compiler would now treat that variable as a constant, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I also tried putting the condition into another variable, either only `time - cb_last_orbital_update` or `time - cb_last_orbital_update - 5E6` and then checking that for either `>5E6` or `>0`, both did not help. Only switching to an int like i mentioned in my workaround helped so far.